# C# XNA :Snake Game, direction problem

Tags: c#, xna

I am trying to do a snake game in XNA but I have some little problems...

I explain :

The Snake has a direction (Enum Type : Haut(=up), Bas(=down), Droite(=right), Gauche(=left)) 
When the player press a direction key this funcion is used :

```
public void SetDirection(Direction newDirection) // Teste les directions impossibles => impossible de faire un demi tour
{
    if (_direction == Direction.Haut && newDirection == Direction.Bas)
    {
        return;
    }
    else if (_direction == Direction.Bas && newDirection == Direction.Haut)
    {
        return;
    }
    else if (_direction == Direction.Gauche && newDirection == Direction.Droite)
    {
        return;
    }
    else if (_direction == Direction.Droite && newDirection == Direction.Gauche)
    {
        return;
    }
    _direction = newDirection;
}
```

In theory, the snake can't make a U-turn.
But it does not work properly (I will try to explain why) :

The snake moves each 100ms. while these 100ms, the snake is waiting for a direction. 
BUT if the snake goes up for example, and if the user presses {Droite(=right), Bas(=down)} or {Gauche(=left), Bas(=down)} while these 100ms, the snake makes a U-turn, and die because he cuts himself.

As a consequence, the user loose the game...

I can't see how to solve this problem.

If I am not clear or if you need any other information, please let me know.

Thanks in advance for your help

PS : I am sorry for the grammar faults but I don't speak perfectly english... :)

PPS : Here is the call to setDirection :

```
case GameState.Infini:
    if (newKeyboardState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Escape))
    {
        CurrentGameState = GameState.Pause;
    }
    else if (newKeyboardState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Up))
    {
        _snake.SetDirection(Direction.Haut);
    }
    else if (newKeyboardState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Down))
    {
        _snake.SetDirection(Direction.Bas);
    }
    else if (newKeyboardState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Left))
    {
        _snake.SetDirection(Direction.Gauche);
    }
    else if (newKeyboardState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Right))
    {
        _snake.SetDirection(Direction.Droite);
    }
```

Comment: Don't let the snake change its direction if it heads backward from its current heading.

Comment: Use mathematical directions and check if the direction is the additive inverse of the current direction and the 100ms movement should be irrelevant to the problem.

Comment: Could you edit the question and add the code that calls `SetDirection`? The issue could be coming from there.

Comment: Where does the 100ms come from? In Monogame/XNA the gameloop is created for you- what made you deviate from this behavior?

Comment: @Jon : it could work ! I will think about why I can implement this in my game

Comment: @Matt Jens Jensen : I thing it would not solve the problem, because the new direction (The diretion the snake will take at the end of the 100ms) at the moment of the {Right, Down} is Right so he would allow the Down Direction...

Comment: @Alexandre Vaillancourt : I added the code

Comment: @Felsir : It is my first game in xna, so I don't know if I can do it an other way, but the snake moves each 100ms at the beginning of the game and go faster when it eats an apple. Plus it is a retro style game so it moves like in old snake games

Comment: I know what the game 'Snake' is. My question is: where do you set the 100ms delay? Do you pause the game loop or have you created your own gameloop?

Answer (score 1):

I finally succeeded to get rid of this behaviour. (Thanks @Jon !)

"Don't let the snake change its direction if it heads backward from its current heading. " 
It actually works :)

Example with 'Up' Direction :

```
int X = _snake._parts.Last().X;
int Y = _snake._parts.Last().Y;
if (newDirection == Direction.Haut)
{
    Rectangle test = new Rectangle(X, Y - _blocCorps.Height, _blocCorps.Width, _blocCorps.Height);
    if (test.Intersects(_snake._parts.ElementAt(_snake._parts.Count - 2)))
    {
        return; 
    }
}
```

Thank to everyone who took some time to help me !

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will work but I did a few tests and it seems to be fine. Define your enum like this :

```
enum Directions
    {
        Up = 1,
        Down = ~Up,
        Right = 2,
        Left = ~Right
    };
```

Now you can a check about the current direction and next direction like this

```
    if(currDit == ~nextDir)
    {
    //the snake will go into itself
    }else
    {
    //change the direction
    }
```

Again I'm not 100% sure that this will work. Someone correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Thank you for your answer ! 

The problem still occurs, but I'm under the impression that it occurs less often... It is more complicated to provoke the problem but it still appears

Comment: @BénédicteRuelle I think you might have to share more code from your game for us to continue helping you. Like where is the SetDirection method being called. Also the timer for the 100 ms would be nice to have a look at that.